# How can I add multiple classes to a Rails form input with erb?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

So this is what I want to do:

```
<% for x in 6..10 %>
  <%= form_for(current_user.responses.new, html:{class: 'col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 vcenter center'}) do |f, index| %>
    <%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width <%= x %>" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work. I want to have two classes on the input field, one being a normal css class using html. The other using an erb variable, in this case 'x'.

I've tried

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width center vcenter", :class => x %>
```

Which only assigns the second `:class`, and overrides the first.

How can I assign both these classes ("my-width" and x) to the form input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width <%= x %>"
```

Isnt valid ruby syntax. Im suprised your not getting an error.

Use string interpolation:

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width #{x}" %>
```

Also its worth noting you should use html classes that are solely a number.

Something like:

```
:class => "my-width-#{x}"
```

Is valid.

Comment: I guess there is no error because its in a string? (So the output would be like <input [...] class="my-width <%= x %>">)

Answer (score 3):

Posting a new answer since Rails4 has a much better way of doing this:

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, class: ["my-width", x] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width <%= x %>" %>
```

This line doesnt really make any sense, since you are putting an erb tag to the string inside an erb tag...
Try

```
<%= f.text_field :response_value, label: false, :class => "my-width #{x}" %>
```